How to merge rows based on set of conditions?
I'm working with IPUMS microdata that looks like the sample below. For every March case, I have one from the ASEC survey (ASECFLAG == 1) and one from the basic CPS survey (ASECFLAG == 2). Each unique combination of CPSIDV, MONTH, and YEAR is data from the same person in the same time period.
But in the "March CPS" rows, I have NA's in ASECWTH, ASECWT, MIGSTA1, and MIGRATE1. In the ASEC rows, I have NA's in HWTFINL, WTFINL, TELWRKPAY, and TELWRKHR (for the latter two, there are also NA's in ASEC rows pre-2022, which is fine).
I need to merge the rows so that instead of two March rows, I have one with the values from ASECWTH, ASECWT, TELWRKPAY, TELWRKHR, MIGSTA1, MIGRATE1, HWTFINL, and WTFINL. Does anyone know of a way to do this?
tibble::tibble(
  YEAR = rep(c(2021, 2022, 2023), c(19L, 15L, 17L)),
  MONTH = rep(rep(c(1L, 3L, 5L), 3), c(4L, 12L, 3L, 1L, 10L, 4L, 4L, 12L, 1L)),
  HWTFINL = c(
    284.9716, 353.6666, 3811.3114, 4019.9385, 362.2898, 470.3117, 441.8812,
    3879.5722, 4939.8717, 4242.0142, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 391.4259, 4284.618,
    3889.7383, 4619.3891, 894.9082, 6759.1703, 5534.8336, 5356.8917, 5086.071, NA,
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 4911.0734, 8434.0448, 5674.1959, 4546.0869, 464.2462,
    5046.3728, 792.1521, 5268.4746, 490.8777, 573.5235, 5132.1223, 5275.3615,
    937.5067, 5829.807, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 611.891
  ),
  ASECFLAG = rep(
    c(NA, 2L, 1L, NA, 2L, 1L, NA, 2L, 1L, NA),
    c(4L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 1L)
  ),
  ASECWTH = rep(
    c(
      NA, 2498.1092, 342.1326, 411.895, 635.3473, 4877.574, 4862.6667, NA, 610.03,
      4690.65, 4786.63, 5161.91, 5378.74, NA, 5201.22, 438.22, 186.1, 670.82,
      2632.76, 5382.53, NA
    ),
    rep(c(10L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 14L, 1L), c(1L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 7L))
  ),
  WTFINL = c(
    381.6691, 353.6666, 3811.3114, 4019.9385, 381.7779, 470.3117, 441.8812,
    3879.5722, 6068.5714, 4242.0142, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 391.4259, 5043.7179,
    3889.7383, 4943.4754, 894.9082, 6759.1703, 5937.219, 5356.8917, 5773.9976, NA,
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 4911.0734, 8434.0448, 5281.4328, 4546.0869, 464.2462,
    5046.3728, 792.1521, 5268.4746, 490.8777, 573.5235, 5941.6991, 5275.3615,
    937.5067, 5829.807, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 611.891
  ),
  CPSIDV = c(
    202101011991021, 202101013159011, 202012028437011, 201912064697031,
    202101011991021, 202103012414011, 202101013159011, 202012028437011,
    202102059320011, 202003064165011, 202012028437011, 202101011991021,
    202101013159011, 202103012414011, 202003064165011, 202102059320011,
    202103012414011, 202102059320011, 202003064165011, 202201063129011,
    202012012452011, 202102057990011, 202102059320011, 202203062616011,
    202201063129011, 202012012452011, 202203062616011, 202201063129011,
    202102057990011, 202102059320011, 202102027935011, 202102057990011,
    202102059320011, 202203062616011, 202301001765011, 202212057398011,
    202301036318011, 202112051141011, 202302001581011, 202302001613021,
    202302007708011, 202212057398011, 202301036318011, 202112051141011,
    202112051141011, 202302001581011, 202302001613021, 202301036318011,
    202302007708011, 202212057398011, 202302001613021
  ),
  CPSIDP = c(
    20210101199102, 20210101315901, 20201202843701, 20191206469703,
    20210101199102, 20210301241401, 20210101315901, 20201202843701,
    20210205932001, 20200306416501, 20201202843701, 20210101199102,
    20210101315901, 20210301241401, 20200306416501, 20210205932001,
    20210301241401, 20210205932001, 20200306416501, 20220106312901,
    20201201245201, 20210205799001, 20210205932001, 20220306261601,
    20220106312901, 20201201245201, 20220306261601, 20220106312901,
    20210205799001, 20210205932001, 20210202793501, 20210205799001,
    20210205932001, 20220306261601, 20230100176501, 20221205739801,
    20230103631801, 20211205114101, 20230200158101, 20230200161302,
    20230200770801, 20221205739801, 20230103631801, 20211205114101,
    20211205114101, 20230200158101, 20230200161302, 20230103631801,
    20230200770801, 20221205739801, 20230200161302
  ),
  ASECWT = rep(
    c(
      NA, 2498.1092, 342.1326, 411.895, 635.3473, 4877.574, 4862.6667, NA, 610.03,
      4690.65, 4786.63, 5161.91, 5378.74, NA, 5201.22, 438.22, 186.1, 670.82,
      2632.76, 5382.53, NA
    ),
    rep(c(10L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 14L, 1L), c(1L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 7L))
  ),
  MIGSTA1 = rep(
    c(NA, 34L, 41L, 36L, 51L, 48L, NA, 51L, 20L, 51L, 48L, 99L, NA, 36L, 24L, 34L, 12L, 40L, 48L, NA),
    rep(c(10L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 9L, 1L, 14L, 1L), c(1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 7L))
  ),
  MIGRATE1 = rep(
    c(NA, 5L, 4L, NA, 5L, 4L, 1L, NA, 5L, 4L, NA),
    c(10L, 4L, 2L, 9L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 14L, 5L, 1L, 1L)
  ),
  TELWRKPAY = rep(c(NA, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, NA, 1L), c(34L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 1L)),
  TELWRKHR = rep(
    c(NA, 10, 40, 60, 999, 40, 999, 40, 70, 16, NA, 40),
    c(34L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L)
  ),
)

Based on a couple existing questions, I tried this because these two variables only exist in the ASEC rows:
tib <- all_ft %>% 
  gather(var, val, MIGSTA1:MIGRATE1) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(val)) %>% 
  spread(var, val)
View(tib)

But I ended up with NA's in every row for my TELEWK variables, and I need to analyze those too.

Perhaps all_ft |> group_by(YEAR, MONTH, CPSIDV) |> tidyr::fill(everything(), .direction = "downup")?

that worked! tysm!!
